# Mode 3 on jQuery qrcode seem to not be working

Tags: jquery, qr-code

I am trying to add an image to the qrcode but `mode 3` seems to not be working.

```
var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
document.getElementsByClassName('qrcodeOut')[0].removeChild(can);
$(".qrcodeOut").qrcode({
    render: 'canvas',
    size: 300,
    fill: fill,
    text: textValue,
    background: backColor,
    mode: 3,
    mSize: 11,
    mPosX: 5,
    mPosY: 0.5,
    src: 'pin.jpg'
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by mod 3 ?

Comment: I mean mode 3. When you try to add image logo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be in image not src

```
var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
document.getElementsByClassName('qrcodeOut')[0].removeChild(can);
$(".qrcodeOut").qrcode({
    render: 'canvas',
    size: 300,
    fill: fill,
    text: textValue,
    background: backColor,
    mode: 3,
    mSize: 1,
    mPosX: 5,
    mPosY: 0.5,
image: $("img-buffer")[0]
});
```

I was able to rectify that also by providing a preview section  on the same page which I use js FileReader() to make the preview the. Thereafter below mode 3 at image I used $("#img-buffer")[0]

Comment: But  my major problem is how to use uploaded image, I was able to rectify that also by providing a preview section <img src=''anything.png'' id="img-buffer" style="display:none"> on the same page which I use js FileReader() to make the preview the. Thereafter below mode 3 at image I used $("#img-buffer")[0]